# How get shown Marker on screen

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I try create android java application with GoogleMap API 2.

Marker.isVisible() return true if marker is on map, including if marker is onmap but not on current screen (piece of map what is now shown to user). I need status of visibility on current screen.

What is best way to get a visibility of my Marker on current screen of map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Maps API documentation, it should be:

```
GoogleMap map = getMap();
LatLngBounds visibleBounds = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
boolean isMarkerVisible = visibleBounds.contains(marker.getPosition());
```